# Estimating the run time of a program according to a given CPU performance

Tags: algorithms, performance, mathematical-analysis

When we have a recurrence relation of a program, as an example:

```
 T(N) = N log N + 9N + 55
```

and the CPU capability let's say (10^6) or any other number. What is the formula or the method to estimate the run time (in second) if we run a program represented by a function of N, and a given N "inputs"?

Comment: That's not a recurrence relation. A recurrence relation expresses T(N) using T(N') for one or more other values N'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you determined that the runtime of your code, on a certain computer, is T(N) = N log N + 9N + 55 microseconds, then that equation determines the runtime. Just substitute N into that equation.